# How to manually calculate Cook's distance

Tags: r, linear-regression

I calculated Cook's distance manually and with the function `cooks.distance` and I got two different results. Can someone please help me understand why?

Below is how I manually calculate Cook's distance:

```
    j=rnorm(100)
    o=rexp(100)
    p=runif(100)
    model=lm(j~o+p)
    O=model.matrix(model)
    P =  O%*% solve(t(O) %*% O) %*% t(O)
    lev=diag(P)
    b<-solve(t(O)%*%O)%*%t(O)%*%j
    RSS <- sum((j-O%*%b)^2)
    s2<- RSS/97                  #three predictors (including intercept (100-3=97))
    residuals(model)^2/(4*s2)*(lev/(1-lev)^2)
```

The above code returns `0.003180925`, but when I use `cooks.distance(model)` R returns `0.004197956`.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: `k` is the number of  the _independent variables_ . So in your calculation, I think you should use `k+1` which is equal to 3 not 4.  So  `(residuals(model)^2/(3*s2)*(lev/(1-lev)^2))[1]` gives the same result with the `cooks.distance(model)[1]`

Comment: You're right! Thanks mate!