# Cook's Distance of Beta Regrssion

Tags: r, regression, outliers

I calculated Cook's distance manually and with the function cooks.distance with Beta Regression and I got two different results. Can someone please help me understand why?

Below is how I calculate Cook's distance (s):

```
require(betareg)
df<-data("ReadingSkills")
y<-ReadingSkills$accuracy
n<-length(y)

bfit<-betareg(accuracy ~ dyslexia + iq, data = ReadingSkills)
yhat<-fitted(bfit)
cook<-cooks.distance(bfit)
hatv<-hatvalues(bfit)
res<-residuals(bfit, type = "response")

RHS<-hatv/(1-hatv)

s23<-var(res)###
p23<-res^2/s23
Response<-(1/2)*p23*RHS

cbind(Response, cook)
```

As recamended here [How to manually calculate Cook's distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62107571/how-to-manually-calculate-cooks-distance) I tried `3` inspite of `2` but same problem.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Take a look at the function itself: `betareg:::cooks.distance.betareg`, it's only a couple lines of code

Answer (score 1):

Here main issuse is type of residual. I was using `Response residual` but `betareg` package used `Pearson residual`.